# SOAP Connection failure with PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am trying to make a SOAP connection request, but receive the following error:

Fatal error: SOAP Fault: (faultcode: HTTP, faultstring: Could not connect to host)

I am attempting to connect to a client's web-service and they needed to whitelist the IP address of the server from where we are connecting to(which is already set). However, through a 3rd soap client such as SoapUI, it works and gives a successful response

Here is my code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("test.wsdl", array('exceptions' => 0));
$result = $client->SendXMLLead();
if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$result->faultcode}, faultstring: {$result->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Here is the link from where we are trying to connect:

https://hqwarranty.com/hqwarranty-soap.php

I am using the following:

```
    $client = new SoapClient("live.wsdl");

$params = array(
   'Leads' => '',
            'RecordSequence' => 12345,
            'Date' => '02/26/2016',
            'TimeOfDay' => '3:25:33 PM',  
            'LastName' => 'test',
            'FirstName' => 'test',
            'EmailAddress' => 'test@test.com',
            'PhoneNumber' => '111-111-1111',
            'Zip' => 94539,
            'CellCode' => 'DTCPPCDA3P',
            'ClientId' => 'DTCB',
            'LeadType' => 'EMAIL',
            'Username' => 'CrossCountryLeadLoad',
);
$response = $client->__soapCall("SendXMLLead", array($params));

/* Print webservice response */
var_dump($response);
```

Update:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Validation failed for: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchema@59109eda errors: [ org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-minLength-valid: Value '' with length = '0' is not facet-valid with respect to minLength '1' for type 'ShortTextRequired'., Line : 9, Column : 26 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '' of element 'DateTime' is not valid., Line : 9, Column : 26 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-minLength-valid: Value '' with length = '0' is not facet-valid with respect to minLength '1' for type 'ShortTextRequired'., Line : 10, Column : 28 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '' of element 'FirstName' is not valid., Line : 10, Column : 28 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-minLength-valid: Value '' with length = '0' is not facet-valid with respect to minLength '1' for type 'ShortTextRequired'., Line : 11, Column : 26 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '' of element 'LastName' is not val in
```

Comment: try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582417/soap-call-works-in-soapui-but-fails-in-php-using-soapclient-object-reference-i

Comment: No response. I edited my post above with the soap request but not response from the server.

Comment: this is not "soapui" related question, please remove the tag!

Comment: i only have soap tag. no soapui.

Comment: I am getting the Fatal error above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check the client definition.  Validation failure is often related to

Soap Version mismatch (is the service expecting 1.1 and you are sending 1.2?);

```
"soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1
```

or a problem in the request message structure, use the try/catch to elaborate more on your attempt;

```
try {
        $response = $soapClient->__soapCall('SendXMLLead', array('parameters' => $inputParams));
    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        echo "<pre>\n -- fault -- \n";
        var_dump($fault);
        echo "\n -- fault code/string --\n";
        echo "SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})";
        echo "\n -- request --\n";
        echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($soapClient->__getLastRequest()) . "\n";
        echo "\n -- response --\n";
        echo "Response:\n" . $soapClient->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
        echo "\n</pre>";
    }
```

this will give you all the message syntax so you can compare against the service and check for any errors in structure, element names, etc...